# What makes the title "PhD" valid?

Tags: philosophy, phd

What are the criteria for a PhD?  Is it mastery in a discipline? (But, then, what is a "Masters" degree?)

If one claims to have a PhD without an issuing institution, can that title be defended as legitimate?

This issue could be relevant in issues of employment (where an applicant has listed a PhD) and to challenge institutionalized PhDs to defend their position amidst a culture that is completely awash in questionable philosophy.

In other words, this is not a criticism of the University as a pedagogical concept.  It is a critique of current incumbents.

[Note:  This question was/is, practically, censored previously.]

[Edit:  Some people claimed that one can't decide what terms mean -- like "PhD", but then, this just pushes the question further: who gets to decide what terms mean?]

Comment: How is this different from “awarding” yourself a PhD?

Comment: Academic titles are conveyed by academic institutions. Note that the legal system in your locale may say more about this topic as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "defend"? Some kind of battle of wits?

Comment: @JonCuster:  It may not be strictly an academic title.  A "doctor of philosophy" suggests a level of expertise in philosophy which is independent of an institution and started BEFORE such institutions.  Further the law should be independent of such a title, except a Doctor of Law.

Comment: No, not a battle of wits, @user37208, but a battle of REASON.

Comment: @thomas:  Well, I'd say IF you award yourself a PhD, you better be prepared to defend it.  Isn't that the essence of anyone who uses the term "doctor" in any field?

Comment: @JonCuster some countries (e.g. Germany) tightly regulate academic titles, but others (e.g. US) have essentially no rules. IANAL, but I think there would be no _legal_ problem with claiming to have a PhD with no institution in the US.

Comment: What do you mean by "_defend_" the title?  I mean PhD students go through a defense process in which they defend their dissertation to demonstrate that they've satisfactorily met the standards that their committee would require to sign-off on their defense form, though it's unclear what alternative you might be proposing.

Comment: @Thomas - one could perhaps claim you have a PhD to your friends with no problem. Claiming in other contexts (such as meeting employment requirements) certainly could have ramifications, legally defensible by the company, at least up to and including termination for misrepresentation. Nobody would believe that somebody can just decide to award themselves a PhD and have it mean anything at all.

Comment: ...honestly, I'm kinda imagining a _Magic the Gathering_ tournament, only with some arm-wrestling and somehow a D&D-like theme worked into it, while people run around screaming like in _Braveheart_.  But that might be the extreme sleep deprivation talking.

Comment: @JonCuster:  Saying it "has no meaning at all" is not what the question implies.

Comment: @Nat  By "defend" I mean something more stringent than what issuing institutions require to defend *their* doctorates -- that ANY (other) PhD can attempt to defeat the title and render it contentious.

Comment: @TheDoctor - Then you should clarify exactly what you mean by the question. I'm really trying to come up with a scenario where a PhD not backed by an academic institution is meaningful in any way whatsoever, that is, is legitimate.

Comment: @JonCuster:  Let's say that the person has knowledge that no other human being has on a topic which is considered important within philosophy.  Fair enough?

Comment: Seems kinda dubious.  If holding a PhD meant having to match the best-and-brightest in some sort of competition, very few people would be able to hold 'em.  But that's simply not what they are.

Comment: @TheDoctor - Nope, not sufficient to claim to have a PhD. We all have knowledge that no other human being has on some topic or another.

Comment: @TheDoctor Holy bowtie! Two timelines crossing together!

Comment: @JonCuster:  I hereby reject your title of PhD, if you have such, as you have made an irresponsible counter-claim that did not address the second part of the sentence at all.  Hence, you have failed dielectic and reason itself.

Comment: @TheDoctor - yet I consider my secret knowledge at least as good as your secret knowledge, so I can claim a PhD in that just as easily as you can claim yours. No, I didn't explicitly address the second part of the sentence since I assumed you could take it to the correct logical conclusion.

Comment: I think this question is approximately meaningless and the OP belies a serious misunderstanding both of the meaning of the phrase “Doctor of Philosophy” and of how the academic world operates in the comments. As such I’ve voted to close it.

Comment: @TheDoctor ok, ok, I give up. In view of the learned discourse you presented in this thread and because of your strong defence against the opposing views therein, I herewith award you the title PhD. Now go and apply for a job. Also, I declare you president of the northern hemisphere.

Answer (score 3):

No. Words don't mean whatever you want them to mean. PhDs generally require:

- getting admitted
- taking classes
- doing research under the supervision of an advisor
- writing that into a dissertation
- defending the dissertation

In principle you could drop out of grad school and do the other steps on your own. While this might be a worthwhile endeavor for you, there is no quality control. A "crackpot" might convince himself and like-minded people (even those with PhDs) that his ideas are right, whereas they will not convince a reputable university to endorse their ideas.

In my office, some of the most experienced and smartest people never got the PhD. They certainly deserve it -- 30 years of research, conferences, grants etc. is a much better qualification than 5 years in grad school (and everyone who matters knows this). But a PhD is an academic qualification, not (only) an award for merit. If you award yourself a PhD and someone calls you on it, they are absolutely not going to buy your explanation about how a bunch of arXiv papers are equivalent to a PhD from a university.

Comment: "Quality control"?  How about the idea of giving a PhD without any requirement of philosophy at all?  Further, you miss the point, a crackpot may be able to convince the pablum that his ideas are right, but if he convinces other PhDs, is that not more than sufficient?  What higher standard could exist?

Comment: Words don't mean whatever you want them to mean. The term PhD refers to "natural philosophy", not philosophy in the modern sense, and is conferred by a university, not by other PhDs.

Comment: Can you defend that to any other PhD @cag51?

Comment: The status quo suggests that the majority of other PhDs agree with me! The onus is on you to convince other PhDs that the current system is broken. Certainly you have not convinced me! But I will not argue the point further here....best wishes.

Comment: Who gets to decide what terms, like "PhD", mean, then?  The onus will not be on me, when you can't answer simple philosophical questions.

Answer (score 1):

No. In the same sense that not everyone has the legal power to marry two individuals, and not everyone can bid in an auction. It depends on the rules.

Comment: You are actually making an inappropriate legal claim here.  Two people can enter a mutual contract (like marriage) without the intervention of the State.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no _legal_ issue with awarding yourself a PhD in many jurisdictions (e.g. much of the US), as long as you don't misrepresent who awarded it. There are many bogus universities in the US and they are [legal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_mill#United_States) -- free speech and all that.

Comment: @thedoctor I said not everyone. But Thomas' point is valid, ignore my answer. Within the social institution of academia, however, the story is likely to be different (declaring yourself to have a PhD does not constitute a PhD, for most people at least).